# containers don't have the same margin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have two containers, as you can see by the code:

```
 <section class="infos shadow">
        <div  class="container">
            <div id="left-info" class="row">
                <div class="col-8">
                    <h4>Curso</h4>
                        <br>
                    <p class="lead text-justify">
                        On sait depuis longtemps que travailler avec du texte lisible et contenant du sens est source de distractions, et empêche de se concentrer sur la mise en page elle-même.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <img src="{% static "images/cards-256.ico" %}" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <hr>

        <div class="container">
            <div id="right-info" class="row">
                <div  class="col">
                    <img src="{% static "images/diamond-256.ico" %}" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <h4>VIP</h4>
                        <br>
                    <p class="lead text-justify">
                        On sait depuis longtemps que travailler avec du texte lisible et contenant du sens est source de distractions, et empêche de se concentrer sur la mise en page elle-même.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And this is the css:

```
.infos{
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}


.infos .container{
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#left-info{
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

#left-info img{
    width: 55%;
}

#right-info{
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

#right-info img{
    width: 55%;
}
```

The site looks exactly like this:

[image]

The problem, as you can see, is that the space between the columns in the first row is not the same as the columns in the second, and i want that the first be like the second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `margin` is totally expected since `img` is taking `width:55%;`of the `col`
if you give the image class `img-fluid` and remove your custom size you added it will solve the problem.

Remove this from your CSS.

```
#left-info img {
  width: 55%;
}

#right-info img {
  width: 55%;
}
```

Then add class `img-fluid` to your `img` tag.

And that is the best option in my opinion

This is how your section looks like. That's why you have a margin.

[image: thats how your section]

on top of that, any element you add on your div will be placed from left to right. I hope that makes sense why you had this margin.

Comment: Did you remove your CSS first?

Comment: `#left-info img{
    width: 55%;
} ` and  `#right-info img{
    width: 55%;
}`

Comment: i fixed it in another way, i put the text-right class on the col of the card img

Comment: Ya but the margin is still there you didn't fix it actually you just moved the image from left to right. the margin is still there. and if you check the design now makes no sense.

Comment: i get it, but i want the margin actually, its part of the design

Comment: Oh ok, buddy. my bad. Glad you were able to make your design works just fine. And I'm sorry for not being any help,